# Using LinearLayout as Custom Options Menu for RecyclerView Item

Tags: android

Looking at many examples (mostly the messaging apps like Facebook etc) - I made a `LinearLayout` which describes all the options (in this case DELETE / EDIT etc along with few other icons) and added it to all items in my `RecyclerView`. When item in `RecyclerView` is ***Tapped and Hold*** I am making it `visible` with an animation.

This works fine for the most part but I feel like this is not the right way as each of my `RecyclerView` item has this `LinearLayout` attached but just hidden (taking too many resources) and then I am changing the Visibility State to `visible` or `gone` in case of Tap and Hold and Sigle Tap respectively.

My RecyclerView Item code is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">       
     <LinearLayout   
        android:id="@+id/item_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
      <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
          android:layout_gravity="top"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:id="@+id/item_image"
          android:layout_width="26dp"
          android:layout_height="26dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
          android:src="@drawable/profile" />
       <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         > 
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:paddingBottom="13dp"
          android:paddingTop="13dp"
          android:paddingLeft="15dp"
          android:paddingRight="25dp"
          android:text="111"
          android:textColor="?attr/chatTextColor"
          android:background="@drawable/rect_message_rec"
        android:elevation="1dp"
          android:textSize="15dp"/> 
         </RelativeLayout>
       </LinearLayout>  
     <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/item_date_content"
      android:layout_width="70dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:visibility="gone"   
       android:background="@drawable/rect_white_border"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/item_datetime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"          
            android:text="24m ago"
            android:textSize="10sp"
          android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#a9a9b0"/>               
       </LinearLayout>           
    </LinearLayout>  
     <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/options_layout"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="45dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:background="@drawable/rect_white_border"
      android:elevation="10dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/opt_1"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_gif"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

    />
      <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/opt_2"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_gif"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

    />
      <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/opt_3"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_download_gif"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

    />
      <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/opt_4"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_push_gif"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

    />
      <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/opt_5"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_pull_gif"

    />      

    </LinearLayout>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

In `android:id="@+id/options_layout"` I am hiding it than showing it when user tap and holds But I felt like there are better ways to do this, If I Look at the other apps, it seems like its an overlay on top of while 'Activity' or `Fragment` as shown in the following screenshot

[image]

The above feels more responsive and light-weight. The other way I thought I could do this is to put this `options_layout` on my `MainActivity` and call it every time when user Tap and holds an item of `RecyclerView` but if this is how it is done then the question is how do you align the layout right on top of RecyclerView item as shown in the above screenshot, the option layout opens just at the right potion to the recycler view selected item.

Any idea how is it done?

Comment: How about adding them as menu item using menu xml file ?

Comment: Adding your linear layout when it is actually required, like view stubing
https://medium.com/p/e56b8c39398b/responses/show

Comment: Sounds good guys, but still doesn't achieve what I am trying to do. Adding to `ViewStub` will reduce the resources but then again in the above Facebook screenshot, it more seems like a single overlay?